# Moving multiple columns of pandas dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I imported using `pandas.read_csv` that is two columns. I manipulated one column, and now would like to `save` all three columns as a `.csv` file. I have been able to save one column at a time, but am unable to get all three (df.Time, df.Distance, and df.Velocity). Here is what I'm working with.

```
`import pandas as pd

 df=pd.read_csv('/Users/path/file.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=['A', 'B'])

 df.columns = ['Time', 'Range']

 df.Time = df['Time'].round(14)
 df.Range = df['Range'].round(14)

 df.Velocity = (df.Range.shift(1) - df.Range) / (df.Time.shift(1) -df.Time)

 df2 = [df.Time, df.Range, df.Velocity]

 df2.to_csv('test5.csv', columns = header)`
```

Comment: Use `df.to_csv('test5.csv')`, which anyway has only 3 columns you need.

Comment: You can specify what columns to save with `to_csv`.

Answer (score 3):

your assignment makes `df2` a list and not a dataframe (`df2 = [df.Time, df.Range, df.Velocity]`).

You probably want:

```
df[['Time', 'Range', 'Velocity']].to_csv('test5.csv')
```

Comment: This outputs `KeyError: "['Velocity'] not in index"`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


data=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data[['column1','column2','column3',...]].to_csv('fileNameWhereYouwantToWrite.csv')
```

You can use like this